# Can coherent light also be polarized?

Tags: optics, polarization

I need to know if it is possible to polarize coherent light using a [Wollaston prism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wollaston_prism). And would the resultant (2) beams of polarized light still be individually coherent?

Comment: Remember that many sources of coherent light (lasers) already produce linear-polarized output. I don't know if the source you're interested produces the same degree of polarization you might achieve with the Wollaston prims, though. And it's not clear if your actual goal might be to obtain two orthogonally-polarized output beam by rotating the prism 45 degrees relative to the source polarization.